# How to interpret pFtest?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, plm

Let's consider documentation of pFtest : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/2.2-5/topics/pFtest.

I don't know where can I find desciption of this test - where can I find $H_0$, $H_1$.

Let's consider output of this test :

```
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
x <- plm(capital~wage+output, model = 'within', data = EmplUK)
xx <- plm(capital~wage+output, model = 'pooling', data= EmplUK)
pFtest(x,xx)
F test for individual effects

data:  capital ~ wage + output
F = 219.06, df1 = 139, df2 = 889, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: significant effect
```

So my intuition says that $H_0$ : OLS model is preferable model and $H_1$ : within model is preferable model. A

My intuition is correct ? Could you explain to me how exactly $H_0$ and $H_1$ are tested ?

Comment: I believe the appendix to this answers your question: http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eecon508/R/e-ta10_R.html#fn1

Answer (score 1):

The following website explains this perfectly under '4.2.2.1 Fixed Effects vs OLS'. If the p-value is < 0.05 then the fixed effects model is a better choice.

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/372492_3e05f38dd3f248e89cdedd317d603b9a.html